# Does ScriptBuilder Require Special Permissions to Access External Applications?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm new to Swift and I'm working on a small menu bar application to get the currently playing song in Spotify using ScriptBuilder. I'm having a problem where the code is not getting a value from the currently playing song when running the code in XCode, however, the code works fine in Playgrounds. I'm wondering if it's a sandboxing issue where I can't actually get that data, or if I just have a misunderstanding of how to structure my code across multiple files. Any guidance is much appreciated.

My current structure in XCode is:

1. AppDelegate.swift - I'm using the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method to set the title of the menu bar icon = current song. (It never gets a value)

   ```
   import Cocoa
   import SwiftUI

   @NSApplicationMain

      class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

      var pt = PlayingTracks()

       let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

           func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
               // Insert code here to initialize your application

               let icon = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
               icon?.isTemplate = true

               let display = pt.getSong()

               if display == ""
               {
                    statusItem.button?.title = ""
               }
               else
               {
                   statusItem.button?.title = display
               }

               //statusItem.menu = statusMenu
           }
           func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
               // Insert code here to tear down your application
           }
       }
   ```
2. GetAudio.swift - This is where I've created the code to get the current song.

   ```
   import Cocoa
   import ScriptingBridge

   let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
   let apps = workspace.runningApplications
   var openMusicApps = [String]()
   //var currentApp = [String]()

   //SPOTIFY:
   @objc protocol SpotifyApplication {
   @objc optional var currentTrack: SpotifyTrack {get}

   }

   extension SBApplication : SpotifyApplication {}

   @objc protocol SpotifyTrack {
   @objc optional var name: String {get}
   @objc optional var album: String {get}
   @objc optional var artist: String {get}

   }

   class PlayingTracks {

       let spotifyApp: SpotifyApplication = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.spotify.Client")!

       lazy var sTrack: SpotifyTrack? = spotifyApp.currentTrack!
       lazy var sTrackName: String = (sTrack?.name)!
       lazy var sArtistName: String = (sTrack?.artist)!

       func getSong() -> (String) {

           return (sTrackName)

       }

   }
   ```
3. This is my playground code that works:

   ```
   import Cocoa
   import AppKit
   import ScriptingBridge

   @objc public protocol SBObjectProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
       func get() -> Any!
   }

   @objc public protocol SBApplicationProtocol: SBObjectProtocol {
       func activate()
       var delegate: SBApplicationDelegate! { get set }
   //    var running: Bool { @objc(isRunning) get }
   }


   // MARK: SpotifyApplication
   @objc public protocol SpotifyApplication: SBApplicationProtocol {
       @objc optional var currentTrack: SpotifyTrack { get } // The current playing track.
       //@objc optional var playerState: SpotifyEPlS { get } // Is Spotify stopped, paused, or playing?
       @objc optional var name: String { get } // The name of the application.

   }

   extension SBApplication : SpotifyApplication {
   }

   // MARK: SpotifyTrack
   @objc public protocol SpotifyTrack: SBObjectProtocol {
       @objc optional var artist: String { get } // The artist of the track.
       @objc optional var album: String { get } // The album of the track.
       @objc optional var name: String { get } // The name of the track.
       @objc optional var albumArtist: String { get } // That album artist of the track.

   }
   extension SBObject: SpotifyTrack {

   }

   class PlayingTracks {


       let spotifyApp: SpotifyApplication = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.spotify.Client")!

       lazy var sTrack: SpotifyTrack? = spotifyApp.currentTrack!
       lazy var sTrackName = sTrack?.name
       lazy var sArtistName = sTrack?.artist



       func getSong() -> (String, String) {

           return (sTrackName!, sArtistName!)

       }


   }


   let np = PlayingTracks()
   np.getSong()
   ```

Comment: I remember that you need to sign your application and add sandbox entitlement with hardened runtime enabled then you need to allow for apple events from hardened runtime. I don't remember exactly but I suggest you try this. Hope helps!